# Imprimir como una lista una respuesta json

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo una ajax que realiza una consulta que devuelve 10 resultados y los obtengo como un json así

```
[
    {"id":1,"code":"A041","description":"INFECCION DEBIDA A ESCHERICHIA COLI ENTEROTOXIGENA"},
    {"id":2,"code":"A042","description":"INFECCION DEBIDA A ESCHERICHIA COLI ENTEROINVASIVA"},
    {"id":3,"code":"A043","description":"INFECCION DEBIDA A ESCHERICHIA COLI ENTEROHEMORRAGICA"},
    {"id":4,"code":"A044","description":"OTRAS INFECCIONES INTESTINALES DEBIDAS A ESCHERICHIA COLI"}, 
    {"id":5,"code":"A045","description":"ENTERITIS DEBIDA A CAMPYLOBACTER"},
    {"id":6,"code":"A046","description":"ENTERITIS DEBIDA A YERSINIA ENTEROCOLITICA"},
    {"id":7,"code":"A047","description":"ENTEROCOLITIS DEBIDA A CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE"},
    {"id":8,"code":"A048","description":"OTRAS INFECCIONES INTESTINALES BACTERIANAS ESPECIFICADAS"},
    {"id":9,"code":"A049","description":"INFECCION INTESTINAL BACTERIANA, NO ESPECIFICADA"},
    {"id":10,"code":"A050","description":"INTOXICACION ALIMENTARIA ESTAFILOCOCICA"}

]
```

este el ajax que uso para hacer la petición:

```
data = {
   code:$('#diagnostico_cie10').val(),
   '_token':$("meta[name='csrf-token'").attr("content")
}

$.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url:"{{url('/enfermedades/show')}}",
  data: data,
  success:function(response){
                    
  },
  error: function (err) {
                 
  }
});
```

y quiero imprimirlos debajo del input:

```
<label for="diagnostico_cie10">{{ __("Diagnóstico CIE-10") }}</label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="diagnostico_cie10">
```

en el `<div id="descripcion_enfermedades"></div>`
La respuesta la obtengo bien pero no se como iterar el json para mostrar cada descripción como un ítem de un `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener la descripción, o lo que quieras, puedes hacer algo así (está todo explicado *in situ* en comentarios del código).

```js
/* 
  Esta sería tu respuesta, la declaro aquí a mano
  a modo de prueba
*/
var response=`[
    {"id":1,"code":"A041","description":"INFECCION DEBIDA A ESCHERICHIA COLI ENTEROTOXIGENA"},
    {"id":2,"code":"A042","description":"INFECCION DEBIDA A ESCHERICHIA COLI ENTEROINVASIVA"},
    {"id":3,"code":"A043","description":"INFECCION DEBIDA A ESCHERICHIA COLI ENTEROHEMORRAGICA"},
    {"id":4,"code":"A044","description":"OTRAS INFECCIONES INTESTINALES DEBIDAS A ESCHERICHIA COLI"}, 
    {"id":5,"code":"A045","description":"ENTERITIS DEBIDA A CAMPYLOBACTER"},
    {"id":6,"code":"A046","description":"ENTERITIS DEBIDA A YERSINIA ENTEROCOLITICA"},
    {"id":7,"code":"A047","description":"ENTEROCOLITIS DEBIDA A CLOSTRIDIUM DIFFICILE"},
    {"id":8,"code":"A048","description":"OTRAS INFECCIONES INTESTINALES BACTERIANAS ESPECIFICADAS"},
    {"id":9,"code":"A049","description":"INFECCION INTESTINAL BACTERIANA, NO ESPECIFICADA"},
    {"id":10,"code":"A050","description":"INTOXICACION ALIMENTARIA ESTAFILOCOCICA"}

]`;

/*TODO ESTO, a partir de aquí iría en el `success`*/
/*Variable para concatenar*/
var html="<ul>";

/*
  El parse no es necesario si indicas dataType: 'json'
  en la petición Ajax
*/
$.each($.parseJSON(response), function (key, value) {
    /* Encadenamos un li por cada description*/
    html+=`<li>${value.description}</li>`;
});
/* Cerramos ul*/
html+="</ul>";

/*Actualizamos el contenedor*/
$("#descripcion_enfermedades").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="descripcion_enfermedades"></div>
```